# Why is there a mysterious page redirection on localhost?

Tags: php, redirection

> I migrated this question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259672/why-is-there-a-mysterious-page-redirection-on-localhost on StackOverflow

I am seeing something extremely weird that I have been seeing for days while developing a site on localhost. When I go to localhost/thesiliconvalleyjournal it immediately redirects me to localhost/pages/siliconvalleyjournal.php.

Notice the absence of 'the'.

I just uninstalled XAMPP using XAMPP's uninstall executable (uninstall.exe) and then reinstalled the latest version from the official website. Immediately before that, I deleted all .htaccess files and ALL directories in the entire localhost (I easily got these back with Git). Nothing that I have tried has stopped that from redirecting.

After reinstalling and resetting settings (because messed up XAMPP settings seems to be the only possible cause), I expect it to give me a 404 not found error WITHOUT redirecting. The actual result is a 404 error AFTER redirecting to `siliconvalleyjournal/pages/index.php`. I DO have a folder called thesiliconvalleyjournal, but I am not reinserting this back until I get this fixed.

**Edit**

The directory I am working in is the default that XAMPP gives. It has no .htaccess files or a thesiliconvalleyjournal folder.

Comment: Did you flush your browser cache?

Comment: Do you use some web framework?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I use PHPMailer but that shouldn't be relevant because I am using the default folder atm.

Comment: @davidgo I don't know what that means, but I restarted my computer, and Ctrl + F5

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache

Comment: @davidgo That actually worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to [clear my browser's cache](https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache) and put the DocumentRoot back to my project and everything works now! I still do not know exactly where it mwas coming from, but this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can check what server replies to a specific request with cURL software, a tool that is a must have for a web developer:

```
curl -I http://localhost/thesiliconvalleyjournal
```

`-I` means "fetch headers only", i.e. HTTP HEAD request. If reply begins with something like

```
HTTP 1.1 302 Found
...
Location: ...
```

or any other 3xx status code, this is indeed redirect, and you will find this mentioned in the web server access log. If there is some other status code (for this case I would expect `200 OK` status), server did not requested redirect.

This redirect can be caused by configuration of the server. The primary source of Apache HTTP configuration is `httpd.conf` file and files included from it. You need to search through all configuration files and find out if there are any Redirect (also Redirect*) statements. Then, identify and remove offending redirect.

You are using XAMPP, this could mean your configuration files are managed with some tool bungled with XAMPP. In this case you have to fiddle with that tool instead of editing configuration files manually, else your edits may get reverted when you use that tool next time, or a tool may fail.

This redirect can also be caused by the php code. For example, if you call a `header()` function you can emit a `Location` header, which implies redirect.

There could be also redirect inside the HTTP meta tag. It could look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://the.redirect.url/and/path'">
```

It is expected to reside in the `<head>` section. This tag then has to either present in the static file, or be generated with PHP.

You can check this with cURL too, but now without `-I` flag, because you now need to review page body.

Comment: I tried this but I also tried what @davidgo said. I had to clear my entire browsing data (lost a bunch of saved passwords, but definitely worth it) and it now works! I still downloaded curl and will use it in future projects/issues. Thank you.